# Spring Boot with custom fork join pool

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm playing around with a custom fork join pool (one that inherits slf4j's MDC contexts from the thread that queues a task) and want to integrate it in a spring boot app, then use it with CompletableFutures.

How can I tell spring that I want to use my fork join pool?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing is having a static method:

```
public static <U> CompletableFuture<U> supplyAsyncWithMdcContext(Supplier<U> supplier) {
    return supplyAsync(supplier, workerPool);
}
```

where the workerPool param:

```
static final ForkJoinPool workerPool = new MdcForkJoinPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(),
        ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory,
        null,
        false);
```

Now when I want to use is instead of a `supplyAsync` I do `supplyAsyncWithMdcContext`